# Diffrence KDE rendering when using scipy gaussian_kde and seaborn kdeplot

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn, auc

As far as the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) tell, the  seaborn [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) work by utilizing the [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde).

However, I got two different distribution when plotting using the `seaborn` and `gaussian_kde`, despite using the same `bandwidth` size.

[image]

In the picture above, the left is the distribution if the data feed directly into the `gaussian_kde`. Wheras, the right ploting is the distribution if the data feed into  `seaborn kdeplot`.

Also, the area under the curve for a given boundary is not similar between these two ways of plotting the distribution.

> auc using gaussian_kde : 47.7 and auc using via seaborn : 49.5

May I know what may cause this difference and is there a way to standardize the output regardless of the method use (e.g., `seaborn` or `gaussian_kde`)

The code to reproduce the above `plot` and `auc` is given below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde


time_window_order = ['272', '268', '264', '260', '256', '252', '248', '244', '240']
order_dict = {k: i for i, k in enumerate ( time_window_order )}
df = pd.DataFrame ( {'time_window': ['268', '268', '268', '264', '252', '252', '252', '240',
                                     '256', '256', '256', '256', '252', '252', '252', '240'],
                     'seq_no': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
                                'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']} )
df ['centre_point'] = df ['time_window'].map ( order_dict )
filter_band = df ["seq_no"].isin ( ['a'] )
df = df [filter_band].reset_index ( drop=True )
auc_x_min, auc_x_max = 0, 4
bandwith=0.5
########################

plt.subplots(1, 2)
# make the first plot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
kde0 = gaussian_kde ( df ['centre_point'], bw_method=bandwith )
xmin, xmax = -3, 12
x_1 = np.linspace ( xmin, xmax, 500 )
kde0_x = kde0 ( x_1 )
sel_region_x = x_1 [(x_1 > auc_x_min) * (x_1 < auc_x_max)]
sel_region_y = kde0_x [(x_1 > auc_x_min) * (x_1 < auc_x_max)]
auc_bond_1 = np.trapz ( sel_region_y, sel_region_x )
area_whole = np.trapz ( kde0_x, x_1 )
plt.plot ( x_1, kde0_x, color='b', label='KDE' )
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.title(f'Direct gaussian_kde with bw {bandwith}')
plt.fill_between ( sel_region_x, sel_region_y, 0, facecolor='none', edgecolor='r', hatch='xx',
                   label='intersection' )

# make second plot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)

g = sns.kdeplot ( data=df, x="centre_point", bw_adjust=bandwith )
c = g.get_lines () [0].get_data ()
x_val = c [0]
kde0_x = c [1]
idx = (x_val> auc_x_min) * (x_val < auc_x_max)
sel_region_x = x_val [idx]
sel_region_y = kde0_x [idx]
auc_bond_2 = np.trapz ( sel_region_y, sel_region_x )
g.fill_between ( sel_region_x, sel_region_y, 0, facecolor='none', edgecolor='r', hatch='xx' )
plt.title(f'Via Seaborn with bw {bandwith}')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# show much the area differ between these two plotting
print ( f'auc using gaussian_kde : {auc_bond_1 * 100:.1f} and auc using via seaborn : {auc_bond_2 * 100:.1f}' )
x=1
```

## Edit

Based on [mwaskon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66599690/6446053), changes of these two lines

```
kde0 = gaussian_kde ( df ['centre_point'], bw_method='scott' )

g = sns.kdeplot ( data=df, x="centre_point", bw_adjust=1 ) # Seaborn by default use the scott method to determine the bw size
```

return

[image]

Visually, the two plot looks identical.

However, the `auc` between the graph still return two different values

> auc using gaussian_kde : 45.1 and auc using via seaborn : 44.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling scipy like this:

```
kde0 = gaussian_kde ( df ['centre_point'], bw_method=bandwith )
```

and seaborn like this

```
g = sns.kdeplot ( data=df, x="centre_point", bw_adjust=bandwith )
```

But the [kdeplot docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) tell us that `bw_adjust` is a

> Factor that multiplicatively scales the value chosen using bw_method. Increasing will make the curve smoother. See Notes.

whereas kdeplot also has a `bw_method` parameter that is a

> Method for determining the smoothing bandwidth to use; passed to scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.

So if you want to equate the results from the two libraries, you need to make sure you're using the right parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @mwaskom. I updated the code and the two plot now looks identical. However, the `auc` from these two plot still different. Appreciate if you can share any input about this.

Comment: Your method for computing AUC will only work if the two curves are sampled on the same grid, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Appreciate if you can suggest how to properly get the AUC for this case. Atleast I know where to start.